# replace html form button with an image

Tags: html, forms

I have the following form. I replace the button with an image "login_button_1.jpg". It works fine, the only problem is that when I place mouse arrow over the image, it remains an arrow and it is not a hand showing the user that this is a button that can be clicked-on. How can change this and make mouse pointer being hand and not arrow?

```
<div class="homepageTable" width:40px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; style="text-align:right" >                      
 <form action="register_form.php" method="POST" id="register_form">                     

    Name <input type="text" size="25" name="name" placeholder="first name"><br/>
    Surname <input type="text" size="25" name="surname" placeholder="last name"><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="" name="submit" style="background:url('img/login_button_1.jpg') no-repeat; width:300px; height:80px; border:none;"/>                                     
  </form>                      
</div>
```

Comment: You can add `style="cursor:pointer;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `cursor: pointer` inside input style, like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="" name="submit" style="background:url('img/login_button_1.jpg') no-repeat; width:300px; height:80px; border:none; cursor: pointer"/>
```